# El archivo program.exe tiene un hash calculado distinto al especificado en el manifiesto

Tags: c#, visual-studio, instalacion

Este es el problema que tenía, busque por internet pero no encontré nada, pero ahora que lo pude solucionar hago la pregunta para auto responderme y lleva la solución que esta tan simple cómo borrar un archivo.

La activación de C:\Users..\Session1.application dio como resultado una excepción. Se detectaron los siguientes mensajes de error:

- El archivo Session1.mdf tiene un hash calculado distinto al especificado en el manifiesto.

Answer (score 1):

la solución es muy simple solo debes de borrar el archivo .pfx, en el ejemplo de la imagen es TemporaryKey.pfx

y volver hacer los pasos para crear el instalador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]